# Update cocapod's pods automatically in build phases

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, cocoapods

If you use [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/), you usually got a step in "Build Phases". It contains following script:

```
diff "${PODS_ROOT}/../Podfile.lock" "${PODS_ROOT}/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null
if [[ $? != 0 ]] ; then
    cat << EOM
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
EOM
    exit 1
fi
```

Why does it only show an error? couldn't it be used to automatically run `pod install` (or `pod update`)?

**UPDATE**

Even if `Podfile` is modified, `Podfile.lock` and `Manifest.lock` stay the same. Then, how can I know `Podfile` changed so I can run the update?

Comment: Seems to me there are two possible solutions to the problem, either `pod install` or `pod update`. So which would you run, and why? Perhaps there are other solutions to the problem too, which makes the automation even harder. If you are sure that a certain solution will always suffice, then you could automate it and add the correct line.

Comment: I don't use bash programming often, would it be enough to remove `cat << EOM
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
EOM` and add `pod update` instead?

Comment: Simply remove it all and do: `diff "${PODS_ROOT}/../Podfile.lock" "${PODS_ROOT}/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null || pod install`. That should work.

Comment: If you want more information I could write up an answer explaining some basic [tag:bash] syntax and pointers.

Comment: That would be great. Also, I think the executing folder must be set to the projects directory when executing pod install. Or is that the executing folder anyway?

Comment: @ShellFish It is not working with the code you provided.

Comment: Ok then remove the lines you said and insert `pod install`, as you said.

Comment: There might also be an issue with the paths, maybe the script wasn't even working. My `Podfile.lock` is in `Project/Podfile.lock` and my `Manifest.lock in Project/Pods/Manifest.lock`. I still was not able to make it work :( maybe `${PROJECT_DIR}` should be used?

Comment: Ok, I executed `env`, `PODS_ROOT` did exist

Comment: everything was correct, It just isn't getting into the if part

Comment: Ok, the problem is that, even when I change the Podfile, Manifest.lock and Podfile.lock remain the same. What can I do?